# Better way to say " We will " we will now hear report from ....."

Tags: phrases

In a meeting where you are going to be asking for a lot of reports from individuals, are there other options, then just repeating "we will hear report from....., over and over

Comment: There are any number of ways to avoid repeating the same introductory words. You could just say ***Next...*** every time after the first, for example.  Are you actually saying all these things *consecutively*, before hearing the first report? If so, just say *We will hear reports from A, B, C, and D*. If you're only saying one at a time (after which that particular person delivers his report), no-one is going to notice or care if you use the same words every time (but they might be glad to hear you say ***Finally**, we will hear a report from Z*, just to reassure them the end is in sight! :)

Comment: You could also emphasize the presenters by saying "Pat Jones will report on..." or "Pat Jones, will you tell us about...?"

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to approach this, but bare in mind there is no good way to avoid some redundancy as that is the nature of the report meeting you described.

You could explain at the beginning of the meeting how you will ask for reports, such as:

> We will hear reports starting from the left of the table and moving
>   around to the right. Please state your name at the beginning of your
>   report, keep it brief and to the point. Hold questions until the
>   conclusion.  Unanswered questions will be added to the parking lot
>   board for later  discussion. Each person will present their report and
>   we will then move on after they finish, continuing until each person
>   is done. I will simply say, "Next, please," when it's your turn.

**OR**

- Pat will now report on XYZ. Please begin.
- John will now report on ABC. Please begin.
- Jill will now report on HIJ. Please begin.